# Can we use NSMutable objects as members of a non-NSMutable class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Suppose we have simple `NSDictionary` class, can one of its objects be an `NSMutableDictionary` object? When we edit a value within the `NSMutableDictionary` object, we are only editing values of the object of `NSDictionary`. Since we are not editing the object of `NSDictionary`, should it be a problem for the non-mutable `NSDictionary` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mutability of a collection class refers only to the ability to modify the *collection* as a whole, not the members. The collection in fact just consists of pointers to the objects it contains; nothing about them is changed. Putting an object inside an immutable collection does not change the object's own ability to be modified.

So, yes, you can modify an `NSMutableDictionary` inside an `NSDictionary`, without difficulty.

```
NSDictionary * myDict;
myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
            [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"This is one string"
                                               forKey:@"sampleKey"]
                                     forKey:@"mutableDict"];

NSMutableDictionary * myMutableDict = [myDict objectForKey:@"mutableDict"];

NSLog(@"%@", [myMutableDict objectForKey:@"sampleKey"];
// Prints "This is one string"

[[myDict objectForKey:@"mutableDict"] setObject:@"Not the same as before" 
                                         forKey:@"sampleKey"];

NSLog(@"%@", [myMutableDict objectForKey:@"sampleKey"];    
// Prints "Not the same as before"
```

Likewise for *any* object (which allows modification) contained inside *any* immutable collection:

```
@interface MyNeatObjectClass : NSObject {
        NSString * neatString;
}

- (id)initWithNeatString:(NSString *)initialString;
- (void)setNeatString:(NSString *)newString;
- (NSString *)neatString;
```

---

```
MyNeatObjectClass * myObj = [[MyNeatObjectClass alloc] 
                                         initWithNeatString:@"Example string"];

NSLog(@"%@", [myObj neatString]);    // Prints "Example string"
NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myObj];
[myObj release];

// instance of MyNeatObjectClass
[[arr objectAtIndex:0] setNeatString:@"Another string"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[arr objectAtIndex:0] neatString]);     // Prints "Another string"
```

Comment: Should just add one major caveat for NSSet since you talk about collections in general.  You should not mutate an object contained in an NSSet if that change would affect the value of hash: or isEqual: for that object.