# Objective-C modifying elements in mutable containers

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need some clarification/advice regarding modifying objects stored in mutable containers in Objective-C.
Let's say I have an `NSMutableArray` called `countries` inside of which there are `NSMutableDictionaries` that store details about each `country`.

```
NSMutableArray *countries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutabelDictionary *country = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[country setObject: @"United States" forKey: @"Name"];

[countries addObject: country];
```

Later I want to modify a `country` stored in `countries`. I can do this either as:

```
[[countries objectAtIndex: 0] setObject: @"United States of America" forKey: @"Name"];
```

or as:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cnt = [countries objectAtIndex: 0];
[cnt setObject: @"United States of America" forKey: @"Name"];
[countries replaceObjectAtIndex: 0 withObject: cnt];
```

the result is the same. With my C++ background, I first thought that `cnt` would be a copy of the object that resides at position 0 in `countries` and after I modify it I have to put the modified object back into `countries`. However, array `countries` would still hold the updated `country` object even if I don't send it the `replaceObjectAtIndex` message.

I would appreciate some advice on how to deal with such situations. Is it any better to explicitly replace modified objects in mutable containers with the new one, or is it completely unnecessary?

Comment: It is indeed completely unnecessary. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915711/can-we-use-nsmutable-objects-as-members-of-a-non-nsmutable-class/5915831#5915831

Comment: Objective-C doesn’t feature pass-by-value or copy semantics as in C++.

Comment: Ok, and what if I remove the `country` from array `countries`? Do I still need to release the `country` dictionary after I removed it from the array? Based on the comments I would assume Yes, but the program crashed when I tried this.

Comment: In your code snippet, you’re leaking `country` since you’ve taken ownership of it via `+alloc` but you haven’t released it. That said, commonly used Foundation collections such as `NSMutableArray` take ownership of objects added to them. When objects are removed from the collection or when the collection is deallocated, the collection releases these objects. So, no, you shouldn’t release an object after removing it from a collection because the collection already does that for you. It’s very symmetric: collection retains objects that are added, collection releases objects that are removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In neither case is a copy of your `NSMutableDictionary` created.  When you call `[countries objectAtIndex: 0]` you are getting a reference to the same `NSMutableDictionary` object that is in the `countries` array.  Any modifications that you make to this object will therefore automatically be reflected in the instance that is returned by the `countries` array.

In short, you have two pointers to a single object instance, and modifying the contents of a mutable collection type does not generate a copied instance of the collection.